# Libgdx Test if line intersects with rectangle

Tags: java, android, libgdx, 2d

Is there a way I can test if a Rectangle object collides with a line? Thanks!

EDIT :

```
public boolean overlapsLineNodes(Vector2 point1, Vector2 point2) {

    boolean collide = false;

    MapObjects mapObjects = play.getWorld().level.getCurrentLevel().getLayers().get("collidable").getObjects();

    Tools.shapeRenderer.setAutoShapeType(true);
    Tools.shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(play.getCamera().combined);
    Tools.shapeRenderer.begin();

    for (RectangleMapObject rectangleObject : mapObjects.getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)) {

        rectangle.setX(rectangleObject.getRectangle().x * 1/64f);
        rectangle.setY(rectangleObject.getRectangle().y * 1/64f);
        rectangle.setWidth(rectangleObject.getRectangle().width * 1/64f);
        rectangle.setHeight(rectangleObject.getRectangle().height * 1/64f);

        float   x1 = rectangle.x, y1 = rectangle.y + rectangle.height,
                x2 = rectangle.x + rectangle.width, y2 = rectangle.y + rectangle.height,
                x3 = rectangle.x + rectangle.width, y3 = rectangle.y,
                x4 = rectangle.x, y4 = rectangle.y;

        Vector2 start = point1, end = point2;

        float[] floatArray = new float[]{x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4};
        polygon.setVertices(floatArray);

        if (Intersector.intersectLinePolygon(start, end, polygon)) {
            Tools.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            collide = true;
        }

        Tools.shapeRenderer.line(point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y);

        Tools.shapeRenderer.rect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);

        Tools.shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);


    }
```

I do this, but it seems not to give me correct results. I am rending all of the rectanglemapobjects in white, and if one collides with the line, then I render it in green. It randomly renders some in green and I cant figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that intersectLinePolygon is the wrong method! I should have been using intersectSegmentPolygon.

Comment: This is the issue I was having. Not understanding the difference betwen line and segment in linear algebra XD Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Compute the intersection of the line with the line defining one edge of the rectangle, determine the whether the intersection point lies between the endpoints of the edge.  Repeat with the opposite edge.  If you get "yes" to either, they intersect.

You do not need to test all 4 edges; just two opposite edges.

If rectangle edges are parallel to the axis ... [x1,y1]-[x2,y1]-[x2,y2]-[x1,y2] ... and your line in question is y = m*x + b, then this becomes simply:

```
ya = m*x1 + b;
yb = m*x2 + b;

collision = ((ya < y1) ^ (ya < y2))  ||  ((yb < y1) ^ (yb < y2));
```

Or, if you order "ya < yb", you can get more precise over whether just touching a corner is considered a collision:

```
collision = ((ya <= y1) && (y1 <= yb)) ||  ((ya <= y2) && (y2 <= yb));
```

Comment: I am currently using the intersectLines method from Intersector. I can't figure out what to pass for the final parameter (Vector2 intersection).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know `start` and `end` point of your line and also `vertices` of rectangle (which you must know to be honest :) ) you can use Intersector's `intersectLinePolygon()` method just like

```
    //definition of variables - of course you can keep your x... y... in float[] array
    float x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 0, x4 = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0, y3 = 0, y4 = 0;
    Vector2 start = null, end = null;

    //...
    //updateing vertices and line start/end points
    //...

    Intersector.intersectLinePolygon(start, end, new Polygon(new float[]{x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4}));
```

If you are using this in `render()` method it is not good to create `new Polygon()` instance every time - better keep one instance somewhere

```
    Polygon p = new Polygon();
```

and then just update it with vertices just before collision checking

```
    p.setVertices(...);
```

Comment: Can you check my edit? I did something like what you said, but am not getting the right results.

Comment: are you sure that your `RectangleMapObjects` has their origin at left-top corner? For Box2D for example the position of body is attached to it's center

Comment: Does it matter? I am rendering everything with shapeRenderer and the rectanglemapobjects line up with the tiles. I don't know what, but something isn't right here :\